# MYSQL sum from two different tables group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
I need to combine each row of these two tables into a row in table3. I managed to get the table1 `SUM` amount but not table2.

Eg.

**table user**

```
 +---------+-----------+
 | user_id | user_name |
 +---------+-----------+
 | 001     |   JOHN    |
 | 002     |   ADAM    |
 +---------+-----------+
```

**table1**

```
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| table1_id | table1_user_id |    table1_amount  |       table1_date   |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|  6        | 001            |    100            |  01/11/2014 10:55   |  
|  7        | 002            |   100             |  01/11/2014 10:55   | 
|  8        | 001            |    50             |  25/10/2014 10:55   |  
|  9        | 001            |   100             |  23/10/2014 11:00   |  
|  10       | 002            |    0              |  21/10/2014 11:00   | 
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

**table2**

```
 +-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
 | table2_id | table2_user_id |  table2_amount |  table2_date       |   
 +-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
 |   1       |    001         |   100          |   15/11/2014 10:55 |    
 |   2       |    001         |   100          |   15/10/2014 10:55 |     
 |   3       |    002         |   100          |   11/10/2014 10:55 |     
 |   4       |    001         |   50           |   11/10/2014 10:55 |    
 +-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Expected Result:

Table3

```
+-----+---------+---------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| id  | user_id | table1_amount | table2_amount |    Year  |  Month  |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| 1   |  001    |    100        |       100     |     2014 |    11   |
| 2   |  002    |    100        |        0      |     2014 |    11   |
| 3   |  001    |    150        |       150     |     2014 |    10   |
| 4   |  002    |     0         |       100     |     2014 |    10   |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

My try but it does not show the expected result. The amount of table2_amount in every row is `NULL` :

```
SQL=" INSERT INTO table3 
      SELECT user_id,SUM(table1_amount),t2.amount2,
      YEAR(table1_date),MONTH(table1_date) FROM table1 a 
      LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT c.table2_user_id,SUM(c.table2_amount) as amount2,c.table2_date
              FROM   table2 c
       GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.table2_date,'%Y-%m'),c.table2_user_id ASC
              ) t2
     on t2.table2_user_id = a.table1_user_id AND t2.table2_date = a.table1_date
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.table1_date,'%Y-%m'),table1_user_id ASC ";
"
```

Comment: what do you mean "it does not work"? did you get an error? did you get bad results? detail please

Comment: I am sorry it did not show the expected result. @no idea for name

Comment: why did you use left join? and how are the tables joined?

Comment: `table1` and `table2` has same attribute : `user_id`  ;`table1`.`table1_user_id` = `table2`.`table2_user_id` =`user`.`user_id`

Comment: well, check the inner select. if it's ok then the join doesn't return any couples and the LEFT word make it so that you only get the rows from table1. i don't think it's good comparing dates unless you are absolotly sure they will be the same

Comment: Store dates as dates/datetimes. Then get back to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a nice task for `UNION`

```
SELECT tx.uid,SUM(tx.a1),SUM(tx.a2),YEAR(tx.d),MONTH(tx.d)
FROM
(
SELECT t1.table1_user_id as uid,
  t1.table1_amount as a1,
  0 as a2,
  t1.table1_date as d 
  FROM table1 t1
UNION
SELECT t2.table2_user_id as uid,
  0 as a1,
  t2.table2_amount as a2,
  t2.table2_date as d 
  FROM table2 t2
) tx
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(d,'%Y-%m'),uid ASC
```

Comment: HI David. Thnak you for your answer but you should know table1_id and table2_id is not the same and they might not have the same number of rows. I have applied your SQL but I got this error `"#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"`

Comment: That doesn't matter for union and are you sure you copied the query completely? That error means you had to miss a column in one of these two subquery selects.

Comment: Actually table id is not even needed, as it is not used, just user id. I removed it from my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the `0 as a1` in the second UNION SQL. However, The result is 0 for each table2_amount row. FYI, number of rows for table2 : 226 rows when it is summed and group by. For table1 there is  569 rows. when I use your SQL, it just shows 569 rows. it didnot combine the rows. it seems like table1 left join table2.

Comment: Can you show me how you edited that query for your actual needs? You may still have a bug in it somewhere. (use pastebin pls)

Comment: Problem found: you used `c.wd as d` but you probably wanted `c.wd_date as d`

Comment: yes. right now , it still shows 569rows with the amount of table2 in each row '0'. I think it is not selecting the table2 date . it is whole using table1 date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64387/discussion-between-xyonme-and-david162795).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David162795 for the enlightening discussion.

The missed point is group INNER QUERY by date and user id when the date from two tables are different.
We need to group them by their individual date in the Inner Query and then group the main SELECT query by the time variable.

This goes my answer for this case :

```
$SQL = "
 INSERT INTO table3 (user_id, table1_amount, table2_amount,Year,  Month)
 SELECT tx.uid, SUM(tx.sum1), SUM(tx.sum2),YEAR(tx.d) as year,MONTH(tx.d) as month 
  FROM 
  (SELECT  b.table1_user_id as uid,b.table1_amount as sum1,0 as sum2,
           b.table1_date as d  FROM   table1 b
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(d,'%Y-%m'),uid ASC

    UNION

    SELECT c.table2_user_id as uid,0 as sum1,
           sum(c.table2_amount) as sum2,c.table2_date   as d1
              FROM   table2 c
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(d1,'%Y-%m'),uid ASC
  ) tx 

 GROUP BY year,month,uid"
```